# Die Hotelzimmer für die Band müssen gebucht werden

Tags: sentence-structure

Is the word order for this sentence correct? Should not the verb come 2nd in the sentence? Why don't we say: "Die Hotelzimmer müssen für die Band gebucht werden."

Comment: You should check the input method on your computer. It shifts the umlaut dots to the right, which makes it hard to read.

Comment: Das klingt, als stamme es aus einem Vertrag, daher wäre es hilfreich mehr über den Kontext zu wissen. Geht es um eine Tournee, und man muss für die Band nicht nur das Hotel zahlen, sondern auch die Buchung übernehmen? Geht es darum, ob Band und Sänger unterschiedlich behandelt werden oder für Band und Rowdies? An wen richtet sich der Text? Wer ist der Verfasser? Was sind die bekannten Umstände?

Comment: @Janka: I will check .... there must be something in my PC ... that explains why many times can not read words with umlaut in many dictionaries!

Comment: @userunknown: it is an organization of a band work by an organizer (Veranstalter).

Answer (score 7):

Both sentences are correct and have slightly different meaning.

First note that in

> Die Hotelzimmer für die Band müssen gebucht werden.

the verb **is** in second position. Of course, for that you have to regard *die Hotelzimmer für die Band* as a unit. So *für die Band* qualifies the Hotel rooms. The hotel rooms are meant for the band.

On the other hand, in

> Die Hotelzimmer müssen für die Band gebucht werden.

*für die Band* refers to *gebucht*. The booking has to be done for the band.